# How do I sort by frequency of a value?

Tags: perl, sorting, count, key

I am trying to create a program to count the different values that occur in a column of a data file. So, it would be something like, if the possible values of a column are A, B, C. The output is something like

```
A   456
B   234
C   344
```

I have been able to get the running counts of A, B and C easily by doing something like this

```
my %count; 
for my $f (@ffile) {

    open F, $f || die "Cannot open $f: $!";

    while (<F>) {
       chomp;
       my @U = split / /;

       $count{$U[2]}++; 
    }

}
foreach my $w (sort keys %count) {
    printf $w\t$count{$w};
}
```

For instance here I am counting the second column of the file in the path given.

How do I sort the output of the `printf` by the counts rather than the keys (or values A, B, C) to get the following output?

```
A   456
C   344
B   234
```

Comment: [perldoc -f printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html): Don't fall into the trap of using a "`printf`" when a simple "`print`" would do. The "`print`" is more efficient and less error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for my $w (sort {$count{$b} <=> $count{$a}} keys %count) {
    print "$w\t$count{$w}\n";
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I'm so used to C#, I forgot how to do a sort in Perl!

Comment: The poster appears to want to sort in descending order, so you would switch a and b.

Comment: @eugene, @runrig thanks this was what i needed, am new to perl so didn't know this trick. one more question, I will generally have counts like this for other columns as well in parallel, so I guess it would be a good idea to put this in a function. can I do that and if so how?

Comment: sub sortByCount {my $count = shift(); for my $w (sort {$count->{$b} <=> $count->{$a}} keys %count) {
    print "$w\t$count->{$w}\n";
}. Then you need to call it with a reference to your hash, ie sortByCount(\%count);

Comment: @Colin Fine: `keys %$count`, not `keys %count`

Answer (score 8):

This is a FAQ:

[perldoc -q sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-%28optionally-by-value-instead-of-key%29?)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %count = (
    A => 456,
    B => 234,
    C => 344
);

for my $w (sort { $count{$b} <=> $count{$a} } keys %count) {
    print "$w\t$count{$w}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A       456
C       344
B       234
```

Answer (score 2):

Some additional comments:

> The output is something like...by doing something like this

You help us help you if you paste your actual code, abbreviated where possible.
When people recreate their actual code, they often obscure or omit the very source of their problem.

```
   chomp;
   my @U = split / /;
```

This splits on space characters and looks for the count after the second space; it's often easier to do:

```
   my @U = split ' ';
```

`split` used with a constant space instead of a regex splits on any sequence of whitespace, like `split /\s+/` except that it ignores trailing whitespace...this is a common enough thing to do that there is this special syntax for it.  Note that the chomp becomes unnecessary.